# pyplot plt.text custom font

Tags: python, matplotlib, fonts

I am trying to make a picture in python in a custom font for some nametags. So the end goal is to have a loop that saves an image with text how I want it.

Afaik this should work, as I changed the rc. But the font of plt.text is still the default. Does anyone know how to make this work?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import font_manager, rc

f_name = font_manager.FontProperties(fname='/Users/me/Library/Fonts/customfont.ttf').get_name()
rc('font', family=f_name)

plt.text(0, 0.6, r"$%s$" % 'test', fontsize = 50)
```

Here is an example of what I get. The ticks change, so rc is set correctly. But the text does not.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem seems to come from the `$ ... $` notation that should override the font properties.

Try:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import font_manager

# Path
path = '/path/to/custom/font.ttf'

# Create FontProperty object
font_prop = font_manager.FontProperties(fname=path)

# Apply font_prop to the text
plt.text(0, 0.6, 'Custom font !', font_properties=font_prop, fontsize = 50)


plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]